# Can I quit my Master program in Germany halfway and obtain a working visa in another country from Germany?

Tags: working-visas, germany

Currently I'm in the second Master year in Germany and have a student residence permit. I know that according to German law, I cannot obtain a work permit in Germany as long as I have not finished my degree. My question here is, if I get a job offer from outside Germany, for example: France or England, can I obtain a French/England working visa when I stay in Germany, and quit the program without finishing the final thesis?

Comment: From whose perspective? The Germans can't prevent you from leaving and the French/British don't mind your current status (beyond the fact that you need to be eligible to apply wherever you apply). Two potential problems: (1) coming back to reside in Germany later (but I assume it's possible, starting the process from scratch without all the benefits a German degree entail) and (2) your ability to secure a work visa anywhere without a master's degree in the first place.

Comment: I want to know that whether my dropping out of school will make a minus point for my chance to receive the working permit? It seems a little bit of vague here, but I just wonder if they will think badly because I haven't finished the program. I heard that some people couldn't get a visa even they got accepted by a company in that country, just because their background have this and that (not illegal of course) or just some reasons that only the immigrant office knows.

Comment: Not having the degree may limit you (depending on work visa category)

Comment: You mean the master degree? Because of course I had a bachelor degree.

Comment: @Balthier Yes, the master's degree. A bachelor would not be enough for many skilled migration programmes and/or to get a job matching the salary or labour market tests requirements for regular work visas in many countries.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you can satisfy the conditions of receiving a work permit outside Germany, you are free to leave the country. Germany has no control over your status abroad and likewise other countries don't care about your German residency.

There might be other issues (e.g. employers in France might prefer to see a Masters degree), but that's out of the scope of your question.